# apparmor DENIED error while executing /usr/sbin/libvirtd for /usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper

Tags: qemu, libvirt, bridge, apparmor

I am running libvirt in user mode (qemu:///session).

I have /usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper with suid set and owner:group set as root:qemu. I have placed the qemu-bridge-helper entries present in /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.libvirtd. Restarted apparmor after the change.

Creation of guest fails.

dmesg shows the following:
[ 4822.650928] audit: type=1400 audit(1519289598.015:142): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" profile="/usr/sbin/libvirtd" name="/usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper" pid=10051 comm="libvirtd" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=6684 ouid=0

What am I missing here? And why do I still get the error?